# Special Characters Insert To MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to get special characters to insert into MySQL, as I can't use them.

This what I got so far...

```
   mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET .mysql_real_escape_string playground='$_POST[playground]' WHERE
     username='$_SESSION[membersusername]'");
```

The text form is

```
<form method="POST" action="playground.php?action=edit">


            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="341">Playground<br><textarea name="playground" id="maxLength" rows="5" cols="50"><? echo $playground ?></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></td>
  </tr>
          </table>

  </form>
```

Hopefully someone will help.

Comment: And thats why you use prepared statements,but more to the point that is wrong syntax.`UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN...`

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
 $playground = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[playground]) ;
 mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET  playground='$playground' 
              WHERE username='".$_SESSION['membersusername']."' ");
```

change that line

```
 <td width="341">Playground<br><textarea name="playground" id="maxLength" rows="5" cols="50"><? echo $playground ?></textarea></td>
```

to

```
  <td width="341">Playground<br><textarea name="playground" id="maxLength" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea></td>
```

Comment: That worked thanks guys! I know I am trying to get iMySQL on server.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your query, so change as follow

```
mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET playground='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['playground'])."' WHERE   username='".$_SESSION['membersusername']."'");
```

As side note i would tell you to use prepared statements with either `PDO` or `mysqli`, your code is infact highly vulnerable to `mysql injections`, [**learn more here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Query is not correct and it should be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE profiles 
SET  playground='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[playground])."' 
WHERE
username='".$_SESSION[membersusername]."'");
```

How ever you should stop using mysql_* functions since they are deprecated and start using mysqli_* functions or PDO with prepare statement.